# how can I repeat something in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning node and Express,  I want to repeat a word in Express
Example

user visits ....../repeat/hello/5  I want "hello" to print 5 times on the browser page,

If they do
/repeat/hello/3 I want "hello" printed 3 times.  How can I do this?  Do I use a for loop if so can I nest the for loop?

Here is my code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//const repeating = require("repeating");

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("Hi there, welcome to my Assignment!");
});

//pig

app.get("/speak/pig", function(req,res){
    res.send("The pig says Oink");
});

//cow

app.get("/speak/cow", function(req,res){
    res.send("The cow says Moo");
});

//dog

app.get("/speak/dog", function(req,res){
    res.send("The dog says Woof, Woof!");
});

app.get("/repeat/hello/:3", function(req,res

    res.send("hello, hello, hello");
});

app.get("/repeat/blah/:2", function(req,res){
    res.send("blah, blah");
});

app.get("*", function(req,res){

    res.send("Sorry, page not found... What are you doing with your life?")

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `req.params` to access the URL params. You can also parametrize the word which you want to repeat:

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:times", function(req,res){

    const { word, times } = req.params;

    res.send(word.repeat(times));
});
```

This way, you can get rid of `/repeat/hello` and `/repeat/blah` endpoints and have only one generic endpoint which handles all words and all numbers

If you want to have a separator, then you can create a temporary array and join it, like this:

```
const result = (new Array(+times)).fill(word).join(',');
res.send(result);
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much, I was on this for hours one more thing I want to do hello, hello, where can I put the space

Comment: If you found this suggestion helpful please consider accepting it as an answer so future readers could benefit from it ;)

Comment: @Sebastian last part of filling an array is done brilliantly. Upvote for that.